# Set Dropdownlist default value dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, default-value

I have this dropdownlist defined in a model

```
tipoUsuario = new List<SelectListItem>();            
tipoUsuario.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Sin tipo", Value = "4" });                
tipoUsuario.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 - Super usuario", Value = "1"});                
tipoUsuario.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2 - Administrador", Value = "2" });
tipoUsuario.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3 - Usuario", Value = "3" });                

public List<SelectListItem> tipoUsuario { get; set; }
```

The view shows a list of elements, each of the elements has a dropdownlist, each of which must have a different default selected value based on a value from the controller. Now i am showing "Administrator" but i want the default value...

```
if (@item.type == "2")
{                      
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.type, item.tipoUsuario, "Administrator")                
}
```

I have being trying lot of options but i don't know how to do it, help me please

Thaning you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "Selected" property to true on your SelectListItem. You could create a population method like:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PopulateTipoUsuario(string default){
    var tipo = from t in source
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = t.Text,
                        Value = t.Value,
                        Selected = t.Text == default
                    };
        return tipo;
}
```

The source variable would be your original collection of SelectListItems:

```
var source = new List<SelectListItem>();            
tipoUsuario.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Sin tipo", Value = "4" });                
tipoUsuario.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1 - Super usuario", Value = "1"});                 
tipoUsuario.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2 - Administrador", Value = "2" });
tipoUsuario.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3 - Usuario", Value = "3" });
```

Comment: I have to set the value from my view because i have multiple dropdownlist, based in a value from my database that i "save" in item.type . Maybe i wrong with my point of view. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... can you create multiple IEnumerable<SelectListItem> properties in your ViewModel (if you are using ViewModels...)? Each of your dropdowns are distinct, you should perhaps look at creating one corresponding property per dropdown.

Comment: thank you! finally i have created a different dropdownlist for each value in my model!

Comment: @Alsan Cool :) Feel free to mark this as the answer if it has helped you.